# Search class names in jars

Tags: grep, java

I'm using this command to search *.jar files for java classes, and I only get the name of the jars that contain those classes:

```
grep -ral --include=*.jar SignonEJB .
```

How can I also get the class names in the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You passed the `-l` option, telling `grep` to only list the file names. That's the names of the `.jar` files, there are no other files involved.

If you want `grep` to output the class names, you need to remove `-l`. But that will print a lot of other junk on the same “line”, because the jars are binary files, not organized by lines. (With GNU grep, you need to pass `-a` to get that output and not just “Binary file … matches”.)

With GNU grep, one possibility is to match the full class name and pass `-o` to output just that:

```
grep -rao --include='*.jar' '[0-9A-Z_a-z]*SignonEJB[0-9A-Z_a-z]*' .
```

or if you want the packages as well

```
grep -rao --include='*.jar' '[$./0-9A-Z_a-z]*SignonEJB[0-9A-Z_a-z]*' .
```

Another approach is to run `strings` on the files first to extract printable strings. (The two commands are equivalent; the sed version chokes on `\&` and newline, the awk version supports all characters.)

```
find . -name '*.jar' -exec sh -c 'strings "$0" | grep SignonEJB | sed "s&^&$0&"' {} \;
find . -name '*.jar' -exec sh -c 'strings "$0" | jar=$0 awk "/SignonEJB/ {print ENVIRON[\"jar\"] \":\" $0}"' {} \;
```

Alternatively (and strictly speaking, more reliably, even though using `grep` is unlikely to turn up false positives), use `unzip` to list the file names, and filter that.

```
find . -name '*.jar' -exec sh -c 'unzip -l -- "$0" | grep SignonEJB' {} \;
```

Comment: The `awk` one supports all characters but backslash (which is why I use `ENVIRON` in the solution I gave). Note that it's _jar_ paths we're talking of here, not _class_ paths.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe (with GNU tools):

```
grep -ralZ --include='*.jar' SignonEJB . |
  xargs -r0IJ unzip -l J '*SignonEJB*.class'
```

Or, maybe a bit more reliable and with an output easier to read:

```
find . -name '*.jar' -exec sh -c 'export i; for i do
    zipinfo -1 "$i" | awk '\''/SignonEJB.*\.class$/{
      print ENVIRON["i"] ": " $0}'\''; done' sh {} +
```